# how to use auto layout when deployment target 5.1 in xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I open my current xcode 4.6 version project in Xcode 5. And it is workin fine bothe I Phone and I Pad in IOS 7.
But I want to develop application compatible with IOS 5 to UP using Xcode 5. But when I set Deployment target to 5.0 and run, there are more auto layout erros are displaying. when I Un tick then it is worked. But in that case we cant run  the application in IOS 6 + with auto layout.

Previously when I used xcode 4.6 and  set deployment target into 5 no issue found in compile time. Exception was occurred only run time. so in that case I used separate storyboard without auto layout for IOS 5.

But in xcode 5 I can't use that method because errors are occurred in compile time. So How I sort out this ??

Comment: Autolayout is not avaialble in iOS5 and hence the error. Apple introduced Autolayout in iOS6.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  Classes that exist in higher SDKs cannot be used on lower ones.

Comment: if you want your code to run both on iOS5 and iOS6+, you can write your autolayout code programmatically and put a compiler macro that checks the OS version.. so every autolayout code must be wrapped with a compiler macro statement ensuring that it's only compiled for iOS 6+.. but that would be a tangeled mess if you ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use auto layout on iOS 5.  It's that simple.  iOS 5 simply doesn't have the auto layout classes, so your app will get errors at run time when you launch it on an iOS 5 device.

You need to turn off auto layout in your xibs and storyboards, set the springs and struts, and write `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as necessary to lay out your views properly.

Since you will have to make your app work without auto layout, there's probably no point in *also* making your app use auto layout when it is available.  Trying to use auto layout only on some devices will mean more code, more testing, and more confusion.  Either change your deployment target to iOS 6.0 and just use auto layout, or use the old layout system on all versions of iOS.